# who can addimperonators in useradmin for a user in aem 6.3

Tags: java, aem, impersonation

I tested to find that only a user can add other to his imperonators list for the other to impersonate. But the other user cannot add by himself to users impersonators list and impersonate. Either a member of adminstrator group or the user himself can add others to the user impersonators list. Is this documented any where and how can we customize any user to addimpersonators like the administrator group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your analysis is right. The list of impersonators is a property at the target user. So the target user can grant another user (the impersonator) the right to act as himself. There is no “impersonation right”, that a specific user group is allowed to impersonate to anybody.

So the use case “Support User Group”, where a group of support users are allowed to impersonate as other business users will not work. Every individual business user must grant impersonation rights to the support user group.

To change the list of impersonators, you just need write access at the target users. Either it is the target user itself, or members of the “user administrators” group, or member of the “administrators” group, or any other user or user group that your project has granted write access on the target user.

If you wanna have the support users group model, you have 2 options:

1. If you are using LDAP Integration, you can add a static value for the impersonation property in the “User Sync” Config. So every LDAP user gets this automatically assigned when he logs in.
2. Write your own service, that uses the UserAdmin-API to assign the impersonators silently in the background. This allows you also to use any business logic you want.

PS:  I haven’t found any good official documentation. Neither at Adobe, nor at Jackrabbit.

Comment: Thank you. We are migrating from cq5.6 to aem6.3 and we see that in cq5.6 a user is able to add himself to another users imperonators list and save and impersonate. But in aem6.3, when the user tries to add himself to another users impersonators list and save and refresh to see that the save actually did not happen. It may be some ootb functionality got changed/updated in aem6.3 which we had overriden in cq5.6 but missed to update according to aem6.3

Comment: Like we just updated the UserInfo.js in apps with the latest UserInfo.js from aem6.3 libs that helped to populate impersonators list for admin. 
But still because of some reason, a user having full access(jcr:all) is unable to add himself as another users imperonators list and save and impersonate.

Comment: After every AEM release you need to test everything against a clean AEM installation. Especially from 5.6 to 6+ changed almost everything. I never want to do that upgrade again. And in a clean AEM 6.3 installation, every user can add impersonators, if the user has read access to the other users. But that can be granted for an entire user group.

Comment: Do we have a fix for the unlock using impersonation issue in AEM 6.3

Comment: Was able to fix the unlock using impersonation issue with a custom servlet issue is in aem6.3.1